# Sparkjava static files 404 after restart

Tags: java, spark-java

I'm using spark java for a small web server. In my main class, I setup the stuff I need:

```
public static void startServer()
{
    if (!starting && !stopping)
    {
        starting = true;

        // Initialize server
        port(port);
        secure(keystoreLocation, keystorePass, null, null);

        // Register all routes
        initRoutes();

        // Start server
        init();
        
        starting = false;
    }
}
```

And in initRoutes, I have:

```
public static void initRoutes()
{
    Spark.staticFileLocation("/public");
}
```

When I run that code, I am able to navigate to localhost and see the contents of my index.html page, which is in src/main/resources/public. I even see this in the log:

```
10:24:17.151 [INFO ] - StaticResourceHandler configured with folder = /public
```

But, when I run a process to restart the server, the staticFileLocation seems to be lost.

Here is my stopServer method and restartServer method.

```
public static void stopServer()
{
    if (!stopping && !starting)
    {
        stopping = true;

        stop();

        try
        {
            // This is temporary until the ability to wait for the service to
            // stop comes along
            Thread.sleep(10 * 1000);
        }
        catch (InterruptedException ex)
        {
            LogUtil.warn("Failed to wait while server shuts down", ex);
        }
        
        stopping = false;
    }
}

public static void restartServer()
{
    stopServer();
    startServer();
}
```

The log shows this line:

```
10:33:52.768 [WARN ] - Static file location has already been set
```

But when I try to access the home page again, I get a 404 and the log says this:

```
10:34:22.260 [INFO ] - The requested route [/] has not been mapped in Spark for Accept: [text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8]
```

My other routes (omitted for brevity) re-initialize just fine. I can restart the server and still navigate to them with no problem.

I don't need the ability to change the static file location, but I would really like for that setting to persist between restarts of the server. Maybe it's the way I'm doing the restart? I couldn't find much information on a proper process for doing so.

Comment: Why are you handling stop & start that way? Also, is that `stop` method the one at `Spark` class?

Comment: Why am I handling them what way? The init() and stop() methods are from the Spark class.

Answer (score 0):

Upgrade to a newer version of Spark-Java i.e. 2.7.0. This issues has been resolved:
https://github.com/perwendel/spark/pull/902